# Ajax query json source and output results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am new to javascript but I am trying to build a script which can query an API via JSON and AJAX and display the results.

This is the code I have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/62Ler/4/

```
$('a').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax_json_echo/",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 5000,
        context: this,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#content').fadeTo(500, 0.5);
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: '0px'
            }, 300);
        },
        error: function (x, t, m) {
            if (t === "timeout") {
                alert("Request timeout");
            } else {
                alert('Request error');
            }
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#content').fadeTo(500, 1);
        }
    });
});
```

Let's say the API has this URL format:

- Base URL: http://api.test.com/v1/search?q=test
- Query for test: http://api.test.com/v1/search?q=test

### Question

How do I replace the div id content with a few of the details from the object json response. For example:

```
Engineering 
Enterprise Recruitment Limited
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in success return function.

```
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: '0px'
        }, 300);
        $('#content').html(data.objects[0].category+'<br>'+data.objects[0].company);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. Sorry to push my luck here but could you explain how to put my keyword query to the API? It is basically whatever is in my input box is what I want to query the API with

Comment: @Jimmy I'm not sure this statement is what you need? -> 
url: '/yourapiurl/' + $('#keyword').val(),